# How to delete a CLion project

Tags: clion

I've been using CLion to run C++ files.  Everything has gone well until today, when I accidentally created a project in the wrong folder.  I deleted all of the files for the project, but for some reason, CLion still thinks the project exists.  How should I fully delete the project?  Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that when you first launch it and you see the projects on the left side that it's listed there? You can hover over it and press DELETE to remove from the project from that list.

Comment: so it will not still stay in my computer's memory or in clion's memory?

Comment: That's just a cache so it doesn't have to scan the filesystem looking for projects. That's about all that is stored about the project other than <PROJECTDIR>/.idea which is already gone.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answered if this answered your question :)